# SAML Service Provider Security

Tags: saml, ws-security

The Identify Provider within the system I am required to test is proprietary software, but the Service Provider is in house software.

I have already implemented some basic attacks (removal of Signature elements, changing values within the XML) but I would like to achieve a higher coverage of attacks without implementing all attacks (surely this is a common problem?).

Is there any frameworks or software for automating SAML attacks? A automated framework was mentioned in the following link, but I have been unsuccessful in locating the code (not sure if it was released):
   https://www.usenix.org/conference/usenixsecurity12/breaking-saml-be-whoever-you-want-be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for the tool used in the article is on [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ws-attacker/)